# Conflict of solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''-6y'+9y = 5t^6e^{3t}$$

This equation has repeated roots for it's complementary solution so what's its Undetermined Coefficients guess solution for it's particular solution? (without solving)

Comment: Do you have _any_ idea? What ansatz had you used if the right-hand side was $e^{2t}$? $e^{3t}$? $te^{3t}$? (It is a good idea to first solve $y''-6y'+9y=0$.) In addition, you have asked many questions now, just inserting images. It is time to learn [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/97236).

Comment: No, I will not click that link. Please just type what you want to type here. Links can become invalid.

Comment: it will (At^{6}+Bt^{5}+Ct^{6}+Dt^{3}+Et^{2}+Ft^{1}+G)e^{3t}) but since it conflicts but it's end part conflicts with complementary solution thus it need to be amended. btw I will learn Mathjax after my finals.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, a problem with the ansatz
$$
(At^{6}+Bt^{5}+Ct^{6}+Dt^{3}+Et^{2}+Ft+G)e^{3t}
$$
is that the part
$$
(Ft+G)e^{3t}
$$
solves the homogenous problem
$$
y''-6y'+9y=0.
$$
Thus, we have to multiply that ansatz by $t^2$ (I hope that you have gotten an explanation for why at some point). This means that a working ansatz becomes
$$
t^2(At^{6}+Bt^{5}+Ct^{6}+Dt^{3}+Et^{2}+Ft+G)e^{3t}.
$$

Comment: I did do the complementary solution, that is why I wrote it has repeated roots so it will involve a 't' in 2nd solution of complementary. Anyway, now I know. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In such a case you might also want to try the factorization
$$
y(t)=u(t)e^{3t}
$$
which reduces the equation to
$$
u''(t)=5t^6.
$$